# Transform svg after click (dropdown) using only html / css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm having issues with this: I'm making sort of a tabs nav and I should accomplish the arrow down to go up on click, when the submenu is collapsed. I have the material icon, but the thing is I can only do it with html5 and css3

```
 <nav class="nav my-4">
    <li class="nav-link px-5 active fw-bold border-bottom border-2">
      <a class="text-decoration-none small" href="#">Título 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link px-5">
      <a class="text-decoration-none text-grey-20 small" href="#">Título 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link px-5">
      <a class="text-decoration-none text-grey-20 small" href="#">Título 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link px-5">
        <a class="text-decoration-none dropdown dropdown-toggle small mw-ch-17" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          Título 4
          <!-- <span class="material-icons-outlined chevron-down">pand_more</span> -->
          <svg .class="chevron-down" width="13" height="8" viewBox="0 0 13 8" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M1.47146 0.294922L6.06146 4.87492L10.6515 0.294922L12.0615 1.70492L6.06146 7.70492L0.0614624 1.70492L1.47146 0.294922Z" fill="#666666"/>
            </svg>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ítem 1</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ítem 2</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ítem 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link px-2">
      <a href="#" type="button">
        <span class="material-icons text-grey-20">
          keyboard_arrow_right
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </nav>
```

This the CSS:

```
.mw-ch-17 {
    max-width: 17ch;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
} 


.nav-link:hover {
  background-color: #E7F0F4;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.nav-link:active {
  background-color: #CFE0E8;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0.255em;
    vertical-align: 0.255em;
    content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='13' height='9' viewBox='0 0 13 9' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M11.09 8.20508L6.5 3.62508L1.91 8.20508L0.5 6.79508L6.5 0.795078L12.5 6.79508L11.09 8.20508Z' fill='%23000000'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    border-top: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0;
}
```

I was thinking maybe there's a way to change the fill color with CSS, but when I try with `fill: black!important`, doesn't work.

Expected: Arrow down at .collapse and arrow up at .collapse .show

And also change the font and icon color on hover and active